# Classloading issue implementing REST client

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a web application running on Tomcat 8 (Windows 10, JRE 1.8.0_111)
that implements a REST client for communication with a 3rd part REST service
(ADLNET xAPI LRS)

When I recently deployed that WAR file on a different server (CentOS, Tomcat
8, Java 1.8.0.11) the application gives a ClassNotFound exception:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.Logger

I have the following JARs in the WEB-INF/lib folder

*jxapi-1.0.3.jar (provided by the ADLNET xAPI project)
*hk2-api-2.4.0.jar
*cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.18.jar
*jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar
*jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar

On running the application with "-verbose:class" I found that the class loading order is different in the two cases. In the error situation, the
'cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.18.jar' is not being used at all.

### catalina.out (OK case)

......
[Loaded org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder$1 from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.18.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Variant$VariantListBuilder from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.VariantListBuilderImpl from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.18.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder from file:/C:/Users/Diptendu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LearnITyLMSv9/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
......

### catalina.out (Error case)

......
[Loaded org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder$1 from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded org.glassfish.jersey.internal.AbstractRuntimeDelegate from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 | [Loaded org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse$Builder from file:/opt/tomcat8/webapps/LearnITyAcademy/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.jar]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/06/17 17:56:50 |

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

may be jar file in WEB-INF is corrupted, so update dependencies with new version and  add new dependency :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
</dependency>
```

and update the project and export WAR file.

Comment: Actually I did add hk2-utils on the Linux server but it led to other errors! Before that I downloaded the WAR file from Linux server to Windows server and it ran without any problem!!